# Songplay (no.4)

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, knowledge, music

Okay, so since the last few were easier than I expected them to be; this `Songplay` riddle will head over to another genre to try and stump some of you up! Good luck to you all!

> Counting the summer by the clouds
>
> Healing neighbors with our sounds
>
> Up 'til now, I've been on this boulder
>
> Next stop home, but not 'til sober
>
> Knowing you can see me now

---

### What is the song and who is it by?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The song is

> *Blame It on This Song* by Chunk! No, Captain Chunk!

Lyrics

> Another summer counting clouds 
>  Singing songs we love too loud 
>  Regretting all our sunburnt shoulders 
>  Guess I'll go home when I'm sober 
>  Wishing you could see me now

So

> If I don't come back, blame it on this song  :)

Comment: I really enjoyed the fact that you added to your answer! Hope you enjoyed the riddle and the song!